# How to build hybrid automation framework in KATALON

Tags: frameworks, katalon-studio

In our project we are using katalon studio. Now we want to implement hybrid framework in katalon. Can any one suggest how to build hybrid automation framework

Answer (score 0):

Katalon studio is just a tool comprised of base eclipse + Selenium + Groovy + Gradle libraries in it.

it can be customisable to any extent. instead of considering katalonstudio as a automation tool. consider that as an IDE. Just prepup the custom code into structurized packages. that should help.  only drawback is that the Katalon only supports Gradle Build tool..